# what is the best and right way to patch a file in inno setup using xdelta (IsDone, run bat)

Tags: inno-setup, inno-setup-v6

I want to patch one big file (~1GB) inside of my installer that I created with inno setup
for creating the binary different patch file I think the best way is using xdelta (if there is any better ways I will be happy to hear it), but I'm not sure what is the best way to apply the created xdelta patch to a file in install time.
I know there is a function name `ISXDeltaExtract` in **IsDone** that I think created for same reason, but I'm not sure how can I use it properly

```pascal
function ISxDeltaExtract(CurComponent: Cardinal; PctOfTotal: Double; MinRAM, MaxRAM: Integer; InName, DiffFile, OutFile: AnsiString; DeleteInFile, DeleteDiffFile: Boolean): Boolean;
```

and I also know I can just create a batch file and extract and run it at the end of my installer, but I don't think its a good idea at all, because the file is kind of big, its going to take some time and I want to somehow show the progress of it to user in installer; that I don't think I can do it with batch file method